# How to compute the rank of the tensor product of two abelian groups?

Tags: abstract-algebra, tensor-products, abelian-groups

I tried to find a formula on the internet for the rank of the tensor product of two abelian groups -- e.g. $rank(\mathbb{Z}\otimes \mathbb{Z})$. If there's one, could you share it with me (with some details before if you want) before I attempt a calculation/proof?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: For finitely generated abelian groups, it's easy:  just use basic (e.g., distributive) properties of $ - \otimes_\mathbb{Z} - $ and the two most basic calculations.

Comment: @Randall That's not really helpful!

Comment: Ha, sorry.  Why not?

Comment: for OP:  To be more helpful, do you know things like $\mathbb{Z}_m \otimes \mathbb{Z}_n \cong \mathbb{Z}_{\mathrm{gcd}(m,n)}$ (which contributes nothing to rank)?  If so, your desired formula will involve some counting of how many $\mathbb{Z}$'s survive after all the tensoring of direct summands.

Comment: By $\mathbb{Z}_m$, for example, you mean $\mathbb{Z}$ mod $m$, right? And no I didn't knew that. What do you mean by "how many $\mathbb{Z}$'s survive after all the tensoring of direct summands"? Sorry, I'm a bit confused.

Comment: No problem (looks like @PedroTamaroff was right!).  Here's a sample calculation:$(\mathbb{Z}_2 \oplus \mathbb{Z}) \otimes (\mathbb{Z} \oplus \mathbb{Z}_4) \cong  (\mathbb{Z}_2 \otimes \mathbb{Z}) \oplus  ( \mathbb{Z}_2 \otimes  \mathbb{Z}_4) \oplus  ( \mathbb{Z} \otimes  \mathbb{Z}) \oplus  ( \mathbb{Z} \otimes  \mathbb{Z}_4) \cong \mathbb{Z}_2 \oplus \mathbb{Z}_2 \oplus  \mathbb{Z} \oplus \mathbb{Z}_4$.  The result has rank $1$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's first assume you are fine with the following properties of tensor products of abelian groups:

- $\mathbb{Z} \otimes A \cong A$ for any abelian group $A$
- $A \otimes B \cong B \otimes A$ for any abelian groups $A$ and $B$
- $\mathbb{Z}_m \otimes \mathbb{Z}_n \cong \mathbb{Z}_{\gcd(m,n)}$
- Distributivity of $\otimes$ over $\oplus$ (up to iso, of course).

Then, for any f.g. abelian groups $A$ and $B$, you can use the fundamental theorem of such groups to compute their tensor products.

Suppose $A$ has rank $r$ and $B$ has rank $s$.  We can write $A \cong F_A \oplus \mathbb{Z}^r$ and $B \cong F_B \oplus \mathbb{Z}^s$ for finite abelian groups $F_A$ and $F_B$ (which are all finite direct sums of $\mathbb{Z}_k$'s for various $k$).  You can then use the properties above to show that 
$$
\mathrm{rank}(A \otimes B) = rs = \mathrm{rank}(A) \cdot \mathrm{rank}(B)
$$
just by distributing everything.  The point is that the finite stuff will never contribute to the rank by the first and third bulleted properties above.

Comment: I see! Thank you very much that was very clear. :^)

Comment: Oh, good.  Glad it helped.